# duplicate data in nodes of cluster in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

why does indexing data into one node of a cluster reflect in all nodes of that cluster in elastic search?

ex: have 3 nodes ex1,ex2,ex3 and all these nodes share same index say `example`. once I update one of node say ex1 why will that reflect in all the three nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the index `example` may have multiple shards and each shard may in turn have one or more replicas. These shards (and their replicas) are distributed across data nodes in Elasticsearch to improve resiliency and increase availability. Read more about them [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_how_primary_and_replica_shards_interact.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html).

Comment: thanks!!! is there any way to avoid this i mean the data i index into one node shouldn't be reflected on the other?

Comment: You can achieve it by setting the number of shards to 1 and replicas to 0. But this is not recommended at all. By doing this you are not taking advantage of the distributed capabilities of Elasticsearch. If this node goes down, your cluster will go down instantly.